# Multiple roles of devise

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I ve seen the link https://github.com/plataformatec/devise for configuring devise for multiple roles. But i am confusing with the fact that how `devise` will recognize that a particular `user` is an `admin`?
Please explain this since there is no any sign up process for the admin. Also i m new to `ror` so please explain me all the steps of configuring the devise for multiple roles?

Answer (score 3):

CanCan is by far your best solution for roles with ruby, I'd suggest checking out [Tony's Usage of Devise/CanCan](http://www.tonyamoyal.com/2010/07/28/rails-authentication-with-devise-and-cancan-customizing-devise-controllers/) to create a roles based system. It took me a little bit to get exactly how to work it out, but now it works wonders for me.

And second way is

I would recommend a role model. In this scenario a user would `have_and_belong_to_many :roles` while a role would `have_and_belong_to_many :users`. This creates a many to many relationship between roles and users. See [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) RailsGuide for more info on associations.

In your CanCan ability.rb file you can do something like this (I am just guessing at your setup):

```
 can :manage, Brand do |brand|
  user.has_role?("brand_manager") && user.brands.include?(brand)
end
```

In your user.rb file it's helpful to write something like this:

```
def has_role?(name)
  role = Role.find_by_name(name)
  (self.roles.include?(role)) ? (return true) : (return false)
end
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Dipak, your link to Tony's Usage of Devise/CanCan is linking to a Rails Guide.

Answer (score 1):

For an updated solution using **Rails 5**, [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) and [CanCanCan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) (CanCan doesn't look like it's supported anymore), check this out:

1. [RAILS 5: USER ACCOUNTS WITH 3 TYPES OF ROLES – DEVISE, RAILS_ADMIN,
   CANCANCAN](https://codepany.com/blog/rails-5-user-accounts-with-3-types-of-roles-devise-rails_admin-cancancan/)

Here is an alternate solution that uses Rails [Pundit](https://github.com/varvet/pundit) and *has_secure_password*:

2. [Implementing Roles and Permissions in Ruby on Rails](http://culttt.com/2016/01/20/implementing-roles-and-permissions-in-ruby-on-rails/)

The advantage of using CanCanCan is that it decouples authorization from user roles whereas a lot of people find Pundit easier to work with less invasive. Both are good.